# Why $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)x^{n+1}$ = $x^3 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)x^{n-2}$?

Tags: real-analysis

When we have a sequence such as $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)x^{n+1}$, why is it true that we can write it as $x^3 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)x^{n-2}$ for example?
Is it only true for $x$ s.t $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)x^{n+1}$converges? So we can say this identity is only true on $(-1, 1)$?
Just a basic idea I'm trying to get a good understanding with...

Comment: The identtiy holds for $x \geq 1$ also in which case both side are $+\infty$. But the infinite sums don't even make sense if $x \leq -1$.

Comment: This is equivalent to the identity$$\lim_{n\to\infty}ka_n=k\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$assuming that either limit exists.

Comment: @PeterForeman So generally it is only true on the interval in which the sequence converges right?

Comment: Well the identity is true for the two formal power series outside of the interval of convergence but if you are considering a real analytic approach this only makes sense for $x$ within the interval of convergence.

Answer (score 0):

The sum $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (n-1)x^{n+1}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (n-1)x^{n-2}\cdot x^3\overset{\text{as $x$ is independent of $n$}}{=}x^3\times\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (n-1)x^{n-2}$$Its kinda taking $x^3$ common from all terms. This holds for all $x$ but of course, when $x>1$, it makes no sense to apply this identity as both sides will be $+\infty$.